# Notebook not working in Binder; OSError: libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, android-binder, open3d

whenever i try to run the following notebook code on binder, i get this error:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 from pyntcloud import PyntCloud
----> 2 import open3d as od
3
4
5 path ="objects\Brigdging.stl"

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/open3d/**init**.py in 
54     # Do this before loading the CUDA pybind dll to correctly resolve symbols
55     try:  # StopIteration if cpu version not available
---> 56         _CDLL(next((_Path(**file**).parent / 'cpu').glob('pybind*')))
57     except StopIteration:
58         pass

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/ctypes/**init**.py in **init**(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
362
363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
365         else:
366             self._handle = handle

OSError: libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libusb should be installed, i checked it in the requirements.txt - but its still not working, only if i run just the notebook on localhost.

```
from pyntcloud import PyntCloud
import open3d as od


path ="objects\Brigdging.stl"
n_size=32



if path.endswith(".stl") :
    test1_or = od.io.read_triangle_mesh(path)
    test1 = PyntCloud.from_instance("open3d", test1_or)
else:
    test1 = PyntCloud.from_file(path)
    
print(test1)
cloud = test1.get_sample(
            "mesh_random",
            n=100000,
            rgb=False,
            normals=False,
            as_PyntCloud=True)

cloud.plot()

voxelgrid_id = cloud.add_structure("voxelgrid", n_x=n_size, n_y=n_size, n_z=n_size)

voxelgrid = cloud.structures[voxelgrid_id]

voxelgrid.plot(d=3, mode="density", cmap="hsv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a simpler `requirements.txt` in a directory named `binder` with just the special packages you need and the versions unpinned.

Then add `apt.txt` file in the `binder` directory with the following contents:

```
libusb-1.0.0
libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Dealing with `libGL` issue that arises if you only add `libusb-1.0.0` based on [here](https://github.com/Fireline-Science/tello_sim/issues/10).

See discussion working this out on [Jupyter Discourse site here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/notebook-not-working-on-binder-open3d-seems-to-break-it/7844?u=fomightez).